# how do i set the cpp_cppckeck opitions?

Tags: c, vim, plugins, cppcheck

I've downloaded the vim plugin `cpp_cppcheck` but have copied it to `~/.vim/ftplugin/c_cppcheck.vim` for it to work with C files too. It seems to work well but I now would like to activate the option `--enable-all` like one can on the shell. In the cppcheck help window it says the following:

> ```
> g:cpp_cppcheck_options  The command line options you want to pass to
>                         Cppcheck. View your Cppcheck documentation for the
>                         possible options.
>
>                         Note that you shouldn't specify a template here! If
>                         you do so, Vim won't be able to correctly parse the
>                         output of Cppcheck for the quickfix-window.
>
>                         The default value is empty (no options).
> ```

but `:c_cppcheck_options` nor `:cpp_cppcheck_options` does not give me anything and when i hit `g` head of the colon, it does not seem to accept it in the command line one the bottom. How can I set the config I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is a global variable. See `:h :let`

```
:let g:cpp_cppcheck_options = 'whatever'
```